# How to have photos received in an email automatically published to website?

Tags: php, email, ftp

I email myself many photos that I post to my website.

It is possible to have photos that are sent to an email of your own domain myinbox@mydomain.com automatically uploaded to a directory in your FTP server? Possibly with PHP?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: You would probably be needing to look at Piping emails using some custom PHP and if you have it, cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it will be pretty complex. If you are using cPanel you can pipe emails to a PHP script. Otherwise you could use a cron job that runs a PHP script that connects to the email inbox to achieve the same purpose.

On the PHP script you would need to break up the email into its components including the attachment. You can then use that information to write it to the server and whatever else you need to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could do something with your mail server to post the information to a php script.

Answer (score 0):

Well... typically to do that you'd need a couple large bits of infrastructure in your website:

1. an API webservice in which some restful qualities could allow you to do a PUT or POST of image data.
2. an smtp server setup that has been programmed to make your remote procedural call to the webservice method for uploading image data.

like this:
[email]->[smtp] (the smtp functionality checks and validates the data) -> API image upload -> success or failure response --> smtp reply to initial email with response message